# Expected payout after a deductible

Tags: probability, expected-value

To my understanding E[X-1] = E[x] - 1.  So why doesn't the following work?

A policy has a deductible of 1 and a capped payment of 5 and losses are distributed exponentially with mean 2.  The expected loss in the range of 1-6 (where variable payment amounts are made) would be $\int_{1}^{6}.5xe^{-.5x}dx$ which is about 1.42.  I would have thought the expected payout was then .42 = E[x] - 1, but it's not.  If you replace .5x by .5(x-1) in the integral you get roughly .86.

I see how the math works, but why doesn't using expectation as a linear operator work here?

Comment: The payout is $0$ for $x \in [0,1)$, $x$ for $x \in [1,6)$ and $5$ for $x \ge 6$. I'm not sure how you got the $1$ above or why you are only considering the range $[1,6]$.

Comment: The losses can be arbitrarily large.  It's the payouts that are limited.

Comment: Payouts less than the max are made in the range of losses from 1 to 6.  When losses are in that range the payout should be one less than the loss amount.  I'm ignoring the fact that the payout would be 5 when X>6, but to get the total expected payout you'd multiply 5 by P(X>6) and add that to what I have above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We first have to understand what $$\int_{x=1}^6 x f_X(x) \, dx$$ represents.  It is the conditional expectation of the ground-up loss between $1$ and $6$, *multiplied by the probability of the loss being in that range.*  In other words, it is $$\int_{x=1}^6 x f_X(x) \, dx = \operatorname{E}[X \mid 1 \le X \le 6]\Pr[1 \le X \le 6]. \tag{1}$$  So the expression $$\begin{align}
\int_{x=1}^6 (x-1) f_X(x) \, dx &= \operatorname{E}[X - 1 \mid 1 \le X \le 6]\Pr[1 \le X \le 6] \\
&= (\operatorname{E}[X \mid 1 \le X \le 6] - 1)\Pr[1 \le X \le 6], \tag{2} \end{align}$$ and unless $\Pr[1 \le X \le 6] = 1$, we see why subtracting $1$ from $(1)$ does not yield $(2)$.

Answer (score 0):

$P(x) = \begin{cases} 0, & x < 1 \\
x-1, & 1  \le x < 6 \\
5,& 6 \le x
\end{cases}$

Let $f$ be the pdf, then
$E[P] = \int_0^\infty P(x) f(x) dx =\int_1^6 (x-1){ 1\over 2} e^{- {x \over 2}} dx + \int_6^\infty (5){ 1\over 2} e^{- {x \over 2}} dx$.

Comment: Sorry, I might need to edit my question.  I'm able to perform that calculation and get the correct answer.  My quandary is more on why isn't the expected payout in the range of losses from 1-6 = expected loss in that range minus 1.  Expectation is linear.

Comment: Expectation **is** linear, but I don't know why you are subtracting one. The **maximumum** deductible is one, but the loss in the range $x \in [0,1]$ is $x$ not $1$.

Comment: Because the payout as a function of losses, X, would be X-1, so you want E(X-1) = E(X) - 1.  E(X) = 1.42, so E(X) -1 = .42, but E(X-1) = .86.  I figured out that expectation is only linear over the entire domain of the function, not a subsection of it.  But still, I can't figure out why intuitively it doesn't work to take the expected loss and subtract 1 to get the expected payout.

Comment: Again, I don't know why you are subtracting one. The full deductable only applies for $x \ge 1$. If you want to approach it this way, you need to subtract $\int_0^1 x f(x)dx + \int_1^\infty f(x) dx =2(1 - {1 \over \sqrt{e}})$.

Comment: Because the insurance company pays $1 less than the loss if losses are in the interval [1,6].

Comment: It pays one dollar less for $x \ge 1$. But not for $x \in [0,1]$ where it pays $x$ less.

Comment: Sometimes I feel my time here is wasted.

Comment: Not sure what this comment means, but I absolutely appreciate everyone's help always.